# Scaffolding/build system for throwaway projects

Tags: c++, c, linux, makefile

This is semi superuser question, but I think it'd fit SO better.

I'm working in the shell for the most of the time, so an IDE doesn't fit my workflow.
Yet I prefer a neatly packed project over a trashy throwaway. I find myself spending WAY too much time writing makefiles (even cmakelists take too much imho, and sometimes feel unintuitive).

Now I've written a note to myself what would an ideal quick build/scaffold system work like, and I'll come around to writing something of the like, unless there is one already. I'd rather put some effort into it that starting my own.

### The note:

Ideally a build system would have the ability to quicky scaffold a project.

```
build <project-name> <language>
```

This would simply make a makefile (or something else handy) with a target with
specified name. It'd prepare it so it outputs an executable named project-name.

This would regulate source files to be compiled:

```
add source <source-file>
```

This would regulate any necessary libraries to be linked:

```
add library <library-name>
```

---

I'd prefer to call it from the shell ad-hoc, and let it create it's own scaffolding stuff, than to dish out my own makefile (or cmakelists). If nothing, then for the sake of autocompletion.

Keep in mind that this is in no way meant for anyhting other than for quick experiments or demonstrations - which is when I don't want to bore others (or myself) with the act of manually scaffolding a project.

To me this seems fairly intuitive and simple way of starting a quick C/C++ project.
So is there such a thing or am I fantasizing a bit? (curse you webdevs and your too-simple-to-believe scaffolding tools!)

**Please suggest an opinionated build/scaffolding system for quick C/C++ projects.**

Comment: Do you want us to recommend a tool that will do this, or explain how to *build* a tool that will do this?

Comment: Why not just copy an existing makefile for a simple project? You can also have a makefile which compiles all cpp files in a dir without needing to add all the files.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of an alias to do that, it seems most appropriate. However I was wondering if something opinionated exists (Even though I didn't point it out, my bad). Propose the answer, it deserves the upvotes, and the best answer perhaps. I'll point out what the question is about aswell, as it is not clear enough.

Comment: You keep using that word, 'opinionated'. I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: As a matter of fact, variable expansion in GNU-make is turing complete. So you can write Makefile-code that generates the apropriate rules using the `$(eval ...)` function. With that you can write a Makefile that scaffolds itself. You can even make it introspect the directory hierarchy for possible source files, infer what objects can be built from it, etc. You can read further input from Makefile syntax files using `include ...` or `$(eval include ...)` to configure the process (like listing which objects belong to which executable, but that's likely above the complexity level you want).

Comment: @Sneftel and I think you're right. More apropriate word would be guided, as I do not want (or would not like) to indulge myself in significant GNU-make wizardry. At least I wouldn't for throwaway experimental stuff. My make wizardry is poor as it is anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple GNU Makefile that I use for single source to program mini projects that is fairly simple to turn all source files to single binary makefile.

```
CSRC = $(wildcard *.c)
CPPSRC = $(wildcard *.cpp)

CLEANF :=

all:

CFLAGS ?= -O2 -g -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -Wextra

ifeq ($(V),)
CCS=@echo "   CC " $@ && $(CC)
CXXS=@echo "  CXX " $@ && $(CXX)
else
CCS=$(CC)
CXXS=$(CXX)
endif

CCMD = $$(CCS) $$(CFLAGS) $$< -o $$@
CPPCMD = $$(CXXS) $$(CFLAGS) $$< -o $$@

define MAKEPROG

$(basename $(1)): $(1)
    $(2) $$($(basename $(1))_CFLAGS)

all: $(basename $(1))

CLEANF += $(basename $(1))

endef

clean:
    @echo "  RM " $@ && $(RM) $(CLEANF)

$(foreach SRC,$(CSRC),\
    $(eval $(call MAKEPROG,$(SRC),$(CCMD))))

$(foreach SRC,$(CPPSRC),\
    $(eval $(call MAKEPROG,$(SRC),$(CPPCMD))))
```

Comment: Haven't found anything more useful than this so far, so I guess it's fair enough to mark it noteworthy, even though I don't really use it. Thanks for sharing anyways :)